# Which version of XPATH and XSLT am I using..?

Tags: java, xslt, xpath

How to know which version of XPATH and XSLT am I using...?

Say I have installed JDK 1.7 then which version of XPATH and XSLT do I have..?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

In XSLT, call `system-property('xsl:version')`. It will return 1.0 or 2.0 depending on whether you are using a 1.0 or 2.0 processor.

In XPath, there's no direct equivalent. But a quick test is to call `current-date()` with no arguments. If this succeeds, you have a 2.0 processor, if it fails, you have a 1.0 processor.

Unless you take steps to install a 2.0 processor such as Saxon on your class path or in the endorsed library, the XSLT processor that the JDK gives you will (today) be a 1.0 processor.

Comment: On which object i have to call current-date() ..? I am using Jdk8.

Comment: current-date() is an XPath 2.0 function. It takes no arguments. XPath functions are not called "on an object".

Comment: In java `javax.xml.xpath.XPath` don't have such static method. Is that means i am using 1.0 version ..?

Comment: It's not a Java method, it's an XPath function. You don't call it from Java, you include the call in your XPath expression.

Comment: <xsl:value-of select="system-property('xsl:version')"/>

Comment: For a quick test to see if you are using version 3, instead of version 2, try using the concat operator ||, rather than the concat function.

Comment: If you need a run-time test, one that's pure XPath rather than requiring XSLT, and that won't cause a failure, try `"2"<"10"`. In XPath 1.0 the strings are converted to numbers and compared numerically, so the answer is true. In XPath 2.0 the strings are compared as strings, so the answer is false.

Comment: just a detail - XPath functions are called on the current object: //div[ 'yo' = text() ]

Comment: @Phlip, no, that's wrong and misleading. For example (a) there are no objects in XPath, and (b) text() is not a function.

Answer (score 8):

Well if you use Java then you have a choice of XSLT and XPath processors. The one built-in in the JDK (I only know of 1.6 but I don't think it has changed in 1.7) is Apache Xalan which is an XSLT and XPath 1.0 processor. There however third party solutions like [Saxon 9](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/) which support XSLT and XPath 2.0. And there are certainly additional XQuery 1.0 implementations for Java, as XPath 2.0 is a subset of XQuery 1.0, you have further choices if you are interested in XPath 2.0.

Answer (score 8):

Try

```
java com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xslt.EnvironmentCheck
```

For example for me this prints

```
#---- BEGIN writeEnvironmentReport($Revision: 1.10 $): Useful stuff found: ----
java.version=1.7.0_11
version.xalan2x=not-present
version.JAXP=1.4
java.ext.dirs=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/ext:/usr/java/packages/lib/ext
version.SAX=2.0
version.crimson=not-present
java.class.path=.
version.ant=not-present
sun.boot.class.path=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/rt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/classes
version.DOM=3.0
version.xalan1=not-present
version.xalan2_2=Xalan Java 2.7.0
version.xerces2=Xerces-J 2.7.1
version.xerces1=not-present
#----- END writeEnvironmentReport: Useful properties found: -----
# YAHOO! Your environment seems to be OK.
```

Answer (score 3):

```
  <xsl:comment>
    XSLT Version = <xsl:copy-of select="system-property('xsl:version')"/>
    XSLT Vendor = <xsl:copy-of select="system-property('xsl:vendor')"/>
    XSLT Vendor URL = <xsl:copy-of select="system-property('xsl:vendor-url')"/>
  </xsl:comment>
```