# Which version of XPath is installed

Tags: powershell, xpath-2.0

I'm using powerShell, and I want to use [lower-case()](http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/fn_lower-case.html) in a XPath.Something like that

```
//Machines/Machine[lower-case(@FQDN)=lower-case('machine2.mydomain.com')]
```

The documentation indicate that I need XPath 2.0, how can I check the version of XPath installed on my server?

Comment: Not sure if i understand your question but are you just looking for lowercase in powershell? On any string you can user `.ToLower()` for example `"IDONTKNOWWHATWEREYELLINGABOUT".ToLower()` would return `idontknowwhatwereyellingabout`. Not sure about the Xpath part of the question?

Comment: I found this in regards to checking xpath version: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7951879/which-version-of-xpath-and-xslt-am-i-using. The higest rated answer in the second paragraph.

Comment: The xpath used with windows event logs is even more crippled.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of [2012, Microsoft was officially not supporting XPath 2.0](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1ff6b816-fe91-49e2-9968-b82307a63317/is-xslt-20-supported-in-net-?forum=xmlandnetfx) in the .NET Framework (which is what you'll be using from PowerShell, unless you pull in a 3rd-party library) and as recently as [last year](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3795831-native-support-for-xpath-2-0-or-xslt-2-0-in-net) it was still not happening. Given that they [said a decade ago](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dareobasanjo/archive/2004/05/13/131166.aspx) that they weren't going to implement it, and it hasn't happened yet - don't count on it ever happening.

See [XPath and XSLT 2.0 for .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525299/xpath-and-xslt-2-0-for-net) for alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in powershell without worrying about case:

```
$xml = [xml](get-content file.xml)                                     
$xml.machines.machine | ? fqdn -eq machine2.mydomain.com


FQDN
----
machine2.mydomain.com
```