# Xpath to find prices in a web page

Tags: regex, xpath

I am trying to extract the prices and currency in an HTML page (for exampe [this webpage](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=camera)) using an XPath expression.

I tried:

```
$x("//*[matches(text(),'^\$\d+\.\d{1,2}')]")
```

in Firefox's console but it prints `undefined`. I look for a solution based on regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

From your example, because you use `matches`, I deduce that you use **XPath 2**. But probably, it is not supported by your browser. Check your [XPath version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7951879/which-version-of-xpath-and-xslt-am-i-using).

Another version that will work for XPath 1 is described below.

Notice that XPath for your `<span>` elements looks like:

```
//*[@id="result_0"]/div/div[3]/div[1]/a/span
//*[@id="result_1"]/div/div[3]/div[1]/a/span
//*[@id="result_2"]/div/div[3]/div[1]/a/span
```

So, you need to use a regular expression for that id and get text from the span.

You can use `matches` (**XPath2**) or `starts-with` (**XPath1**) for the first part and `text()` to get the text from `span`. So, to test it in your browser, use something like this:

```
$x('//*[starts-with(@id,"result_")]/div/div[3]/div[1]/a/span/text()')
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried your suggestion, however for some reasons I need the regular expression, I also doubt if my Firefox really support XPath 2?

Comment: However in this page the currency is $, but I would like an expression which extract the currency and the price as separated items

Answer (score 0):

What about the following regex? :

```
\/\/\*\[\@id="result_\d+"\]\/div\/div\[3\]\/div\[1\]
```

Actually all you need is going to the source of the page from the relative Xml tag and get its XPath by right click and choosing `copy xpath` then if you want to use a regex for all cases you need to escape the regex characters and use `\d+` for the result number.

Comment: Maybe I asked my question badly, I need regex for the price and currency, by the way, which environment you are talking about? I see no `copy xpath`

Comment: I thought you want a regex for traversing the x/html file manually! if you are using a web scraper that is the proper way for such tasks the xpath gotten from browser may doesn't match with your scraper xpath selector. So can i ask you whats your tools for this task?

Comment: I need it actually to use in a paper (article), it should be in standard XPath, a way to describe how one can find currency and prices out of web pages.