# If-else statement in XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I have such a personal id number: 53012393715. The 10th number means gender. I want to use if-else statement to do such an operation. At first I should get the 10th number from id, in my case it's 1 (one). If the number is even (0,2,4,6,8) it means woman, otherwise (1,3,5,7,9) it means man. I need to get the gender in my output XML file.

I tried to get the 10th number using concat function, but it doesn't work, also I don't know how to use if-else statement correctly.

My input XML file:

```
<ClientList>
  <Client>
    <IdNumber>53012393715</IdNumber>
  </Client>
</ClientList>
```

This one output XML file I want to get:

```
<ClientList>
  <Client>
    <Gender>man</Gender>
  </Client>
</ClientList>
```

Comment: What *Have* you tried? What is your *actual* output? Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and also check out [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `substring` to get the 10th item

```
 <xsl:variable name="gender" select="substring(IdNumber, 10, 1)" />
```

In XSLT, `xsl:if` is just a single statement, with no else. If you want to do "if/else" you use `xsl:choose`

```
<xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="number($gender) mod 2 = 0">Male<xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise>Female<xsl:otherwise>
<xsl:choose>
```

Putting this together gives this...

```
<xsl:template match="Client">
  <Client>
    <xsl:variable name="gender" select="substring(IdNumber, 10, 1)" />
    <xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test="number($gender) mod 2 = 1">Male</xsl:when>
       <xsl:otherwise>Female</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </Client>
</xsl:template>
```

However, if you could use XSLT 2.0, you would be able to do this...

```
<xsl:value-of select="if (number($gender) mod 2 = 1) then 'male' else 'female'" />
```

Comment: Thank you so much. By the way, how to check if I could use XSLT 2.0? It seems easily to use than XSLT 1.0.

Comment: It depends what processor you are using. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7951879/which-version-of-xpath-and-xslt-am-i-using to check if your processor supports XSLT 2.0