# How to locate child nodes having attribute xpath="1" and xpath="2"

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, xpath-2.0, xpath-1.0

I'm trying to locate a web element that have two child nodes as:

```
<div _ngcontent-c2="" class=" " title="Twelve (Start date is 31| 0 user)" xpath="1"></div>
<div _ngcontent-c2="" class=" " title="Twelve (Start date is 31| 0 user)" xpath="2"></div>
```

I tried `//div[contains(@title,'Twelve (Start date is 31| 0 user)')][1]` to get the first element but didn't work for me.

Comment: Neither `@title` attribute starts with `'Form '` like your XPath does.

Comment: Do you want to select those two element or their father?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find element by attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26304224/find-element-by-attribute)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### xpath="1"

`xpath="1"` attribute is the reference of [xpath v1.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/)

### xpath="2"

`xpath="2"` attribute is the reference of [xpath v2.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/)

For the record *Selenium* supports *XPath v1.0* only.

A bit more of the outerHTML including the *parent tag* would have helped us to construct a more canonical answer. Moreover the information about the *Language Binding* you are using is also missing. However to locate the first element you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *visibilityOfElementLocated()* and you can use the following can use the following xpath:

- *Java*:

  ```
  WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[contains(@title,'Start date is 31') and @xpath='1']")));
  ```
- *Python*:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@title,'Start date is 31') and @xpath='1']")))
  ```

> Here you can find a detailed discussion on [What are the differences between versions of XPath (1.0, 2.0, 3.1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51374344/what-are-the-differences-between-versions-of-xpath-1-0-2-0-3-1)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with **CSS**:

```
div[xpath='1']

div[xpath='2']
```